# Firefox not rendering some pages well

Tags: linux, arch-linux, firefox

I recently installed ArchLinux on my macbook Alu. I've installed the nvidia proprietary graphics, and Gnome3.

I have Firefox 10 installed with pacman.

However Firefox is not rendering some pages well (like in MacOs).

The page width outfit the screen size and elements not appearing where they should.

Can someone tells me if it comes from my installation or from firefox in general?

(I've also tried to disable hardware accelaration but same result).

Thank you.

Comment: Most of the time this is caused by not having the right fonts. Unfortunately I do not know Arch and what its font packs are called, and if there's a main one that has all the common fonts in it.

Comment: This is very difficult to answer. It could be a bug on the site. Give an example of an URL that doesn't display correctly, and post a screenshot that shows the bad rendering.

Comment: what do you mean by "disable hardware acceleration"? If you want to rule out the graphics driver, you can use `vesa` as the X11 video driver. There are several ways things can go wrong with web rendering, and please keep in mind that the web was *never* intended to have pages rendered the same way across different computers, so "where they should" is more like "where they perhaps would in browsers that render this in the very same way and ind computers which share the same subset of fonts and other settings".

Comment: For instance http://www.crashplan.com is not rendering well on linux.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To fix this problem under ArchLinux just install the ttf-ms-fonts package from AUR